# Variable evaluation in LateX

Tags: variables, latex, evaluation

I have the following piece of latex code:

```
\def\a{1}
\def\b{2}
\def\c{\a+\b}
\def\d{\c/2}
```

I expected \d to have the value 1.5. But it did not. However,  adding parenthesis to the definition of \c like

```
\def\c{\a+\b}
```

Doesn't work either, because if I use \c somewhere, it complains about the parenthesis. Is there a way to evaluate  \c before dividing it by 2 in the definition of \d? Like:

```
\def\d{\eval{\c}/2}
```

(I made that \eval up to show what I mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [calc](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) package for arithmetic operations. The package [fp](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) works with real numbers.

For discussing LaTeX problems you're kindly invited to visit [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember that `\def` is about creating replacement text. It will always give you back what you put in, quite apart from not knowing anything about maths. If we assume you are using e-TeX (likely), then for integer expressions you might do

```
\def\a{1}
\def\b{2}
\edef\c{\number\intexpr \a + \b \relax}
\edef\d{\number\intexpr \c / 2 \relax}
```

This uses the e-TeX primitive `\intexpr`, which does integer mathematics. For real numbers, Stefan is right that the [fp](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) package is the best approach.